# Debugging program freeze on another machine

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have an application that is exhibiting strange behavior that I'm having trouble figuring out.  It works fine on my machine and many user machines.  However on some machines, seemingly at random, it just hangs.  I was able to get on a support online meeting with a user and run a trace on their system while it was stalled.  Here is a trace screen shot:

[image]

It appears that for 29.6 out of 30 seconds some threads were waiting on each other to complete, and were called almost 6,000 times.  I've been trying to google this and have looked plenty here as well and from what I gather this suggests a thread deadlock condition.  The problem is that this application only uses background threads in a few locations and this constructor shouldn't be one of them as far as I'm aware.  Here is the code for the constrcutor:

```
        InitializeComponent();

        if (KMApplication.Settings != null)
        {
            _useWin10 = KMApplication.Settings.ForceSpellingMode == SpellChecker.SpellingModes.Windows10
                || (KMApplication.Settings.ForceSpellingMode == SpellChecker.SpellingModes.Automatic && Utility.IsWindows10());
        }
```

The XAML for this control is pretty lengthy but I can copy it if necessary...

So my question is if anyone can tell from that what is going on, or if not what is the best way to go about looking for the issue here?

Comment: Do you use external DLL ??? Maybe you are missing those dll's on the other machines...

Comment: You could always look for certain weaknesses in the program and try catching potential exceptions. When an exception occurs, just show a basic dialog with the error message (or create your own depending on what happens). If you can't display a dialog, write it to the console. Also, double check the second system has the appropriate framework installed.

Comment: I do use external dlls, but I've verified that they are all installed on the target machine that is having the issue so I don't think it's that.  Besides wouldn't it throw an exception instead of just stalling?  Also on the machines having issues it seems to stall for about 6 or 7 minutes and then comes back

Comment: @kill4silence I guess what I'm asking is how do I go about looking for weakness?  Since it seems like a threading issue I'm not to sure where to start.  I've looked for any thread calls in my code and I have very few and I'm not sure how they could lock...

Comment: If the wrong framework is installed, I believe the program doesn't run. If it does, but crashes, it has to be something else. As far as looking for weaknesses, how you go about that is entirely dependent on the code you've written. Any time you're unsure of something, debug it. You'd be amazed how one little thing can make everything go wrong, even if it doesn't seem so wrong at first.

Comment: I'm looking at a user machine, and right now it is hanging... It has 2 threads going, one is the main thread and the other I don't know.  The main thread traces down to a property change notification, but the second thread only has ExecutionContext.Run with a sub-item of WaitHandle.Any.  Is there a way to find out what the other thread is waiting on or what the property change is that is on the main thread?

Comment: For anyone still looking I may have been wrong about the source of this issue.  I was debugging with another user having apparently the same issue and after a lot of headaches (like 4.5 hour remote session... ugh) I finally figured out that it was the spell checker taking forever to load.  I was hitting the issue described at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2153484 and they ended up having hundreds of invalid paths so it was taking 11 minutes to load the UI.  I haven't been able to verify with the original user that it's the same issue but will update when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a ridiculous amount of debugging and testing I figured out that this is not related to threading at all.  It actually was related to spell checking of all things.  It ended up being the issue shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167463/spell-check-textbox-in-win10-slow).  If you look at the answer by am7zd they describe exactly what the issue ended up being.  Not sure why it shows up this way in the trace but it's misleading, it's actually registering a bunch of dictionaries in all the text boxes and taking forever to create them. In the case of this user there were like 1800 non-existent files in that setting and once I cleared them up everything went back to normal speed.

Hopefully that helps someone running into similar issues...