# Spelling with textboxes and custom dictionaries slowing down my application in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, textbox, spell-checking

I am using a WPF TextBoxes inside my WinForm application for spell checking. Each time I create one, I load the same file in as a CustomDictionary. All has been fine until recently. Now, they take a long time to load, up to a second. Some forms have 30 or more, meaning delays of nearly half a minute. This seems to be the case Windows 10 (not Windows 8 as I originally posted). The application is running under DotNet 4.0, I have tried 4.5 and 4.6 (not 4.61) and all versions are slow.

I have seen sfaust’s question [Spell check textbox in Win10 - Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167463/spell-check-textbox-in-win10-slow/34168464#34168464) and am7zd’s answer. Thanks to these, I looked at the *GLOBAL* registry key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Spelling\Dictionaries. I have 580 entries (after pruning out entries without matching files) and still things are slow.

At present, every time I create a TextBox and add a custom dictionary to it, a new entry seems to be generated in _GLOBAL_

- Is there a better way of doing things than loading the custom dictionary in from file every time?
- Is there a way of re-using the same entry in _GLOBAL_ every time instead of creating a new one?
- Is there a clean way of clearing previous entries in *GLOBAL* created by my application and their matching .dic files when closing the application (or on restarting it)?
- I could clear _GLOBAL_ completely each time I start my application. This brings back the speed I want, but what is the downside?

Any advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No answers from anyone else, so this is what I have done:

1. I made sure I use CustomDictionaries.Remove on all textboxes with custom dictionaries before closing the form they are on. This gets rid of new entries in _GLOBAL_ and the related files in AppData\Local\Temp.

But there will be times when things go wrong or the user just ends the task, leaving _GLOBAL_ entries and .dic files in place, so:

2. I decided to take things a stage further. When I start my application, I will not only clean entries in _GLOBAL_ that don't have matching files (as suggested in the previous post referenced above), but also to remove all entries referring to .dic files in AppData\Local\Temp. My theory being that anyone who has left entries there didn't mean to, otherwise they would probably have saved the .dic file in a different folder (as Microsoft Office does).

   ```
       try
       {

           string[] allDictionaries = (string[])Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Spelling\Dictionaries", "_Global_",  new string[0]);

           if (allDictionaries.Count() > 0)
           {
               List<string> realDictionaries = new List<string>();
               bool changedSomething = false;

               foreach (string thisD in allDictionaries)
               {
                   if (File.Exists(thisD))
                   {
                       if (thisD.Contains(@"\AppData\Local\Temp\"))
                       {
                           // Assuming that anyone who wants to keep a permanent .dic file will not store it in \AppData\Local\Temp
                           // So delete the file and don't copy the name of the dictionary into the list of good dictionaries.
                           File.Delete(thisD);
                           changedSomething = true;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           realDictionaries.Add(thisD);
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       // File does not exist, so don't copy the name of the dictionary into the list of good dictionaries.
                       changedSomething = true;
                   }
               }

               if (changedSomething)
               {
                   Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Spelling\Dictionaries", "_Global_", realDictionaries.ToArray());
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(this, "Error clearing up old dictionary files.\n\nFull message:\n\n" + ex.Message, "Unable to delete file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
       }
   ```

I am still wondering if it is totally safe to clear entries in _GLOBAL_ that refer to files in AppData\Local\Temp. Surely people shouldn't be leaving important stuff in a temp folder... should they?

What would be really nice would be an overload to CustomDictionaries.Add that allows us to set the name and folder of the .dic file, allowing all the textboxes in the same application to share the same .dic file and making sure we don't leave a load of redundant entries and files with seemingly random names hanging around in the first place..... please Microsoft.

Comment: Really good explanation mate. I'm facing right now the same problem (win8 worked great but now in win10 is working slowww in just some machines). I think I will implement a workaround like yours, but I'm just wondering how many side effects could imply removing the _Global_ variable content (e.g. losing MS Word misspelling capabilities? etc)

Comment: Word and (as far as I can see) all Office products use a single entry something like this in _GLOBAL_:  C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\16.0\fbf00836\Proofing\RoamingCustom.dic. So it's not effected by clearing entries in AppData\Local\Temp. I'm wondering if it is only DotNet programs with custom dictionaries that use this Temp folder for the .dic files, but haven't been able to find anything else written about this.

Comment: I have the same speed issue as you saw, but I don't have the registry key at all. Under `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Spelling` I only have a `(Default)` key and an `Options` subfolder. Any idea where I might find it, or what else I can do to solve this issue? Thans

Comment: Sorry, I don't. When I look at this key with he CustomDictionary added, _GLOBAL_ appears (didn't see it straight away, until I remembered to press refresh in RegEdit - doh!).

Comment: @Michael Not sure what you mean. I don't have a Dictionaries entry under Spelling at all, and so don't have a  _GLOBAL_ key to watch. I tried f5 while the custom dictionary was added, but nothing changed. Any ideas?

Comment: @Avrohom, sorry, been away fro SO for a while. If you don't have that key, I don't know where else to look. It was sfaust's question (link in my original question) that got me looking at these registry entries to start with and it got me to a result that works for me, but I'm not a spelling/dictionary expert.

Comment: @Michael OK, thanks for the reply. This has become a major issue for us, and we have found that many users don't have the reg key, and even for those that do, cleaning the key and temp files only helps until they restart the app.

Comment: @Avrohom, could this be related to registry entries in the Windows default user and all users profiles? If not, I wonder if it is something completely different giving the same symptoms.

Comment: @Michael I didn't know there was a default user! Sadly it didn't have the Dictionaries reg key either. Not sure what you meant by "all users profiles" though. Where would I look for those? I searched the entire registry for keys named "Dictionaries" but didn't find any. Thanks for the reply. Any further suggestions would be very welcome

Comment: @Avrohom, when looking at the C:\Users folder on my machine, I see "All Users" as a hidden folder, as well as "Default" and "Default User". I guessed that it has it's own registry entry, but don't know for sure. May be worth a little research to find out. Sadly I'm all out of ideas now. Hope you get to the bottom of the problem.

Comment: We have a similar problem: *.dic files are created by our .net app and the MCShield.exe from MCAfee always scans them, as they are created each time a form is loaded containing fields with spellchecking. We noticed that MCAfee slows down the app and thus the form may take from several seconds to several minutes to load, until all those *.dic files are scanned.

Comment: @Aymen, we were using Sophos when I was dealing with this. Anti-virus could well have been causing the slowdown for us too,,,, but I didn't try turning it off. I haven't used WinForms for a while now, thank goodness we can leave the browser to sort out spelling in web applications.